# Distorted Unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, spectral-theory

Let $U$ be an unitary and $D$ be a diagonal matrix. We know that for all vectors $v$ on the sphere $Uv$ is on the sphere and, $$\langle Uv,Uv\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle.$$ What are the vectors $v$ on the sphere at origin such that $$\langle DUv,DUv\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle?$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\langle DUv,DUv\rangle = 
(DUv)^*DUv = (Uv)^*D^*D(Uv)^* = (Uv)^*|D|^2(Uv)^*
$$
Setting $w = Uv$, this is just $w^*|D|^2w$.  So, noting that $\langle w,w \rangle = \langle v,v \rangle$ the question can be rephrased as "when does $w^*|D|^2w = \langle w,w \rangle$"?

Now, suppose $w$ is given by $w = \pmatrix{w_1 & \cdots & w_n}^T$ and $D$ is given by
$$
D = \pmatrix{d_{11}&&\\&\ddots&\\&&d_{nn}}
$$
Then we have
$$
w^*|D|^2w - w^*w = w^*(|D|^2-I)w= (|d_{11}|^2-1)|w_1|^2 + \cdots + (|d_{nn}|^2-1)|w_n|^2
$$
The above will be equal to zero if $w_i = 0$ for all $i$ such that $|d_{ii}|\neq 1$.

Comment: sure what does the variety w look like?

Comment: I wouldn't call $w$ a variety per se... $w$ is just another vector.  All I'm saying is that
$$
\langle DUv,DUv\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle \iff \langle Dw,Dw\rangle=\langle w,w\rangle
$$
Where $w = Uv$ and conversely, $v = U^*w$.  What this solution set looks like depends on what $D$ looks like.

Comment: D is diagonal and does this help? Is there a easy way to study this and we have the information that w is on a sphere.

Comment: To some extent.  The solution set for $w$ will be the span of the standard basis vectors $e_i$ for all $i$ such that $|d_{ii}| = 1$.

Comment: could you elaborate your points in the answer?

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: $|d_{ii}|\leq 1$ is possible and so $w_i=0$ if $|d_{ii}|\neq 1$ need not hold.

Comment: Well... that's an embarrassing oversight.  At the very least though, this should be easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Since $U$ is unitary, $UU^t=Id$, hence your question is equivalent to ask for vectors  s.t. $\langle Dv,Dv\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle$. Since $D$ is diagonal, this is the case for vectors that are eigen-vectors of $D$ with eigenvalue $\pm1$.

Comment: if $Dw=\pm w$ then $v=U^{-1}w$ is the vector you are searching for.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not including complex eigenvalues?

Comment: The eigenvalues are $\sqrt 1=\pm1$, even in $\mathbb C$. so I am considering complex numbers.

Comment: @user126154: If $D$ itself is unitary, the eigenvalues of $D$ can be arbitrary _unit_ complex numbers.... :)

Comment: For complex matrices, we say that $U$ is unitary when $UU^* = Id$, where $*$ denotes the conjugate of the transpose.

Comment: yes, if U is unitary w.r.t. the herimitian product, you're right.